# Find the domain and range of the function $f(x) = \frac{x}{x^2 - 16}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

> $$f(x) = \frac{x}{x^2-16}$$

$$f(x) = \frac{x}{(x-4)(x+4)}$$

I can see that the domain is $\{x|x\neq \pm 4\}$

I'm not sure what to do for the range though.

$$y = \frac{x}{(x-4)(x+4)}$$

$$x = y(x-4)(x+4)$$

From here, to me it looks like there can be no value of $y$ that will create an unreal number $x$, so I would say the range of $f(x)$ is any real number.

But I'm not sure I did this the mathematically correct way? 
Is there a more correct way to verify the range of this function or is this the way it's done?

Comment: Why is $-4$ included in the domain?  You are correct that the range is the set of all real numbers.

Comment: aahh, yes, you're right. Let me correct that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your domain is correct.

For the range, since 
$$y = \frac{x}{x^2 - 16}$$
we obtain
\begin{align*}
y(x^2 - 16) & = x\\
yx^2 - 16y & = 0\\
yx^2 - x - 16y & = 0
\end{align*}
For $y$ to be in the range, this quadratic equation must have real roots.  Hence, we require that the discriminant be nonnegative.  Since the discriminant is 
$$\Delta = b^2 - 4ac = (-1)^2 - 4y(-16y) = 1 + 16y^2$$
the discriminant is positive for every real value of $y$.  Hence, the range is the set of all real numbers.

Comment: That's really insightful. Thanks, that's what I'm looking for. Rules I can know and apply. @N.F.Taussig

Answer (score 4):

The range is the set of all values that $y$ can take.

Since $y=\dfrac x{(x+4)(x-4)}$, over $(-4,4)$, $y$ is continuous.

Now when $x=-4+\epsilon$, $y\to\dfrac{-4+\epsilon}{\epsilon(-8+\epsilon)}=\dfrac{4-\epsilon}{\epsilon(8-\epsilon)}$ and as $\epsilon\to0$, we see that $y\to\infty$.

And when $x=4-\epsilon$, $y\to\dfrac{4-\epsilon}{-\epsilon(8-\epsilon)}$ and as $\epsilon\to0$, we see that $y\to-\infty$.

By the Mean Value Theorem, there exists a value $t\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $t=\dfrac x{x^2-16}$, so the range is the whole of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thankyou also, @TheSimpliFire . This is helpful too and answers my question and not just solves the problem.

Comment: @Bucephalus You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

there's two asymptotes ---> $x=4$ and $x=-4$
so the domain is: $$x \in \mathbb R \setminus \text{{-4,4}}$$

but for all other $x \in \mathbb R$, f(x) is exists, so the range is $\mathbb R$

Answer (score 0):

The domain is given by $$x\ne \pm 4$$ and the range is given by all real numbers.